# JavaScript alert onclick onchange if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, events, onclick, alert

I am trying to display an onclick alert if the box is filled in with the world "hello", while a different alert should pop up in "hello" is not typed. 
Not sure what I am doing wrong here:

The HTML:

```
<form>
<input id="box" placeholder="type hello" onchange="sayHello()" style="display: block;" />
<input type="button" onclick="sayHelloTwo()" value="Click me" />
<p id="hidden" style="display: none;">
 HELLO
</p>
</form>
```

The JavaScript:

```
function sayHello() {
var answer = "hello";
if (answer) {
alert("Click for Hello!");
} else {
alert("you need to type hello!");
return false;
 }
}

function sayHelloTwo() {
document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("hidden").style.color = "#909090";
document.getElementById("hidden").style.fontSize = "40px";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the actual value that the user entered in the box, and then compare it to the value you want (the value inside your `answer` variable).

There are several ways to do so, one of the is using

```
document.getElementById('box').value
```

(Where `box` is the `id` of your element).

Here is a working example:

```js
function sayHello() {
  var answer = "hello";
  var text = document.getElementById('box').value;
  if (text == answer) {
    alert("Click for Hello!");
  } else {
    alert("you need to type hello!");
    return false;
  }
}

function sayHelloTwo() {
  document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("hidden").style.color = "#909090";
  document.getElementById("hidden").style.fontSize = "40px";
}
```

```html
<form>
<input id="box" placeholder="type hello" onchange="sayHello()" style="display: block;" />
<input type="button" onclick="sayHelloTwo()" value="Click me" />
<p id="hidden" style="display: none;">
 HELLO
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Dekels answer some more, the click event also has an event property attached to it that you can use to get the value, like this.

```
function sayHello(e) {

  if (e.currentTarget.value == "hello") {
    alert("Click for Hello!");
  } else {
    alert("you need to type hello!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the element value directly as a parameter `this.value` in your html.

Notice that to make the code case insensitive you must convert the value to lowercase and than check the if statement `value.toLowerCase() !== 'hello'`

Code:

```js
function sayHello(value) {
  if (value.toLowerCase() !== 'hello') {
    alert('You need to type hello!');
    return false;
  }

  alert('Click for Hello!');
}

function sayHelloTwo() {
  var hidden = document.getElementById('hidden')
  hidden.style.display = 'block';
  hidden.style.color = '#909090';
  hidden.style.fontSize = '40px';
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="box" placeholder="type hello" onchange="sayHello(this.value)" style="display: block;" />
  <input type="button" onclick="sayHelloTwo()" value="Click me" />
  <p id="hidden" style="display: none;">
    HELLO
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error in checking condition for answer

```
function sayHello() {
    var answer = "hello";
    if (answer == "hello") {
        alert("Click for Hello!");
    } else {
        alert("you need to type hello!");
        return false;
    }
}
```